# why do the cells in the table view resize when I add a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints

so I've been stuck on this problem for hours. I am using a custom UITableViewCell that is in a nib file. Very simple app that, creates a random item that has a Name, Serial Number and $. The items are displayed in the table. I edited the constraints for the custom cell in the xib file. All the lines are blue and it displays perfectly. It's just when I click to add an item all the item's cells above become smaller and squash together, this breaks a constraint. Just have no idea why the cells are changing size when I click add! If I click on a cell for detail and then go back to the table view screen the cells will be formatted correctly again. Hope someone can help!

I have posted a link to the code files: http://ge.tt/74OIim62/v/0?c

This is from (Big Nerd Programming Ranch Book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't implement one of required UITableView methods:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80.0f;
}
```

Or set rowHeight as fixed value by doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80.0f;
    ...
}
```

Or you need to set UITableView to auto-calculate height for you (recommended and most convenient in iOS 8).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0f;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I used the third one! Thank you so much. Works perfectly now. Spent HOURS trying to fix this tiny thing. Book never mentions it. Life saver. Thanks again !

Comment: Probably book was written to iOS 7, those features are from iOS 8 and UITableView behavior was changed a bit in last updates

Comment: having another slight problem now (the final one), I am now trying to use Dynamic Text Size in the cell. BNRItemCell has a method -(void)updateInterfaceForDynamicTypeSize to assign the font size. If I change the system font size in the settings the serial number will not be displayed properly for small sizes (top and bottom chopped off). It works okay for large sizes though. No idea why. Have the field linked to IBOutlet UILabel *serialNumberLabel. Any chance you could have a peek? (updated code at : http://ge.tt/3PyFLs62/v/0?c )

Comment: You don't need all of this, read this through: http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ Especially part with how to setup autoLayout